# virtualenv: cannot access lib: No such virtualenv or site directory

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am using Google Cloud Platform to create a Django based http API, which uses Google's cloud SQL API and Machine Learning API.

I made a django-mysql app on my pc and is able to test it successfully on localhost. I want to deploy this app to Google Cloud.

Following are my relevant files:
**app.yaml:-**

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
- url: .*
  script: mysite.wsgi.application

libraries:
- name: MySQLdb
  version: 1.2.5
- name: numpy
  version: "1.6.1"


skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?- ^(.*/)?.*~$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
- ^(.*/)?\..*$
- ^env/.*$
```

**appengine_config.py:-**

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
import os
vendor.add(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'lib'))
```

I am getting a 500 error on api home. [here](https://neuralnet-171308.appspot.com/). I am getting the following error report on my dashboard:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 351, in __getattr__
    self._update_configs()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 287, in _update_configs
    self._registry.initialize()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 160, in initialize
    import_func(self._modname)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/b~neuralnet-171308/20170628t204601.402294282540056750/appengine_config.py", line 18, in <module>
    vendor.add('lib')
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/vendor/__init__.py", line 44, in add
    'No such virtualenv or site directory' % path)
ValueError: virtualenv: cannot access lib: No such virtualenv or site directory
```

Originally the **appengine_config.py** contained:-

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

vendor.add('lib')
```

As suggested [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#requesting_a_library), I changed it to the current file.

I deploy my project using `gcloud app deploy`. I do not understand how to use `gcloud_sql_proxy` for deploying.

I am for sure having a `lib` folder in same directory as `app.yaml`. I do not know what I am doing wrong. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The prior configuration as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env#setting_up_libraries_to_enable_development) seems to be correct. And as shown in this sample [app](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/flask/tutorial), try installing dependencies with pip:

```
pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Do I run this command on my local machine or do I need to do it on the App Engine instance? If the later, how?

Comment: This should be marked as a correct answer. Thank you so much!
@Code-Apprentice You can run it in your localmachine by `dev_appserver.py`

Answer (score 1):

Run the below command in root directory of app in cloud shell and deploy.

**pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt**

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

```
libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.11"
```

to your app.yaml file.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. we are here trying to avoid `libraries` and trying to use the lib