# Python App Engine application not showing latest code deployed

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am very new to app engine and python, I have deployed a google app engine application using python 2.7, in google cloud shell. I have made lot of changes and they were showing correctly,

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml
```

But after some time I made certain changes adding new log statements and conditions,while deploying it shows no error, but in the logs the new statements are shown and still it prints the old statements from main.py file. Even if use the delete old version

```
      gcloud app services delete <appname>
```

and once again deploy the new version making it as 1 still the logs show the old version only in the app engine logs, even if I close the cloud shell session and deploy again it still shows the old version,  The app engine is triggerred by a cloud pub-sub message justFYI, I am at a loss why the app engine still takes the old code even if delete the old versions completely. Any Help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was deploying the application from cloud shell, and that application required certain libraries which i installed through pip install -t lib requirements.txt

Sometimes the cloud shell got hanged and a new machine was created so when I deployed the application using

```
 gcloud app deploy
```

without using the pip install -t lib again maybe that was causing the problem and the code was not deployed properly now again i used

```
pip install -t lib
```

and all the libs got installed and then i did

```
gcloud app deploy
```

and now it started working.
Thanks to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/45743581/1403505

Answer (score 1):

If you go to `cloud console > app engine > versions > tools > debug` you can see the source code of the existing versions, so you can make sure if the changes are being transmitted as expected or not, also double check that you are in the right directory when doing the `gcloud app deploy` command. When deploying double check the that the project id is correct, and after each deploy the version id will be shown, try verifying the source of a recently deployed version